# connect(null, null, null, { withRef: true }) unconventional?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a need to pull some content out of a child component such that the parent (or just generally higher-level) component can dispatch an action creator with the data of the inner child component.

Previously I was invoking a function on the child ref like `this.refs.child.doStuff()` until I found it was becoming difficult to keep track of the ref in whatever parent component I needed the method data in. Everytime there is a HOC or some other kind of compositing wrapper I need to add more code to pass the ref up the chain that I need. Not to mention there was a lot of duplicate code in each child function that was standard to all.

```js
// child.js
class InnerComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  doStuff = () => {
    calculateFrom(this.state.content)
    // and then do stuff with it..
    // I've since made this more redux-y by just returning the data
    // out to an action dispatcher
  }
}

const SomeHOC = (args) => {
  return (Component) => class extends React.Component {
    proc(wrappedComponentInstance) {
      // I went with using the getWrappedInstance func here
      // to mimic conect(.., .., .. { withRef: true }) for
      // basic compatibility with a higher level function that
      // dives through the wrappedInstances to get to the bottom one
      this.getWrappedInstance = () => wrappedComponentInstance;
    }

    render() {
      const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, { ref: this.proc.bind(this) });
      return <Component {...props} {...this.state} />
    }
  }
}

// I actually don't need the connect() here but will on other components of the same style when they're not in their wrapped form
export default connect(..., ..., null, { withRef: true })(SomeHOC()(InnerComponent);
```

```js
// parent container (there are multiples of these in my app)
class Container extends React.PureComponent {
  determineContent = (...) => {
    return React.createElement(this.state.content, {
      // so I can get to the composited inner element...
      ref: (element) => { this._compositeElement = element; },
      ...viewletProps
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // ...
    System.import(`${dynamic}.jsx`).then((content) => {
      this.setState({ content });
    });
  }

  renderButtonContainer = () => {
    // Here's where things get weird...
    if (!this.doStuff) {
      this.doStuff = ((() => {
        // hook into my ref
        const compositeElement = this._compositeElement;
        // deep-dive through to get to the base
        let base;
        if (compositeElement && typeof compositeElement.getWrappedInstance === 'function') {
          base = this._compositeElement.getWrappedInstance();
          while (typeof base.getWrappedInstance === 'function') {
            base = base.getWrappedInstance();
          }
          if (typeof compositeElement.doStuff === 'function') {
            this.doStuff = base.doStuff;
          }
        }             
      })());
    }

    return (
      <div hidden={!this.doStuff}>
        <span><i class="myIcon" onClick={this.doStuff}></i></span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      { this.renderButtonContainer() }
      <div>
        { this.determineContent(...) }
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

I've since pulled all of that out and am now dispatching an action per Redux-style and letting my reducer handle what needs to happen (just a synchronous internal call that executes immediately using the data in the action; I'm still unsure if this being in the reducer is bad form)

However, since I need my child components to still return the invocation of their `doStuff()` (`getStuff()` instead) at the time of the parent component's choosing, I find myself stuck with my same ref issues.

Am I going about this all wrong? It almost seems to me like for each child component I have I need to be storing this always-changing data from `getStuff()` inside my state model and just pass it down into the component? But I'd anticipate that would be too disassociating from the actual component and the rest of my app doesn't really care about that.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, *none* of that seems like a good idea at all.  Even if it's technically possible, it completely goes against the intended usage of both React and Redux.

Refs in general are an escape hatch, and should be used only if necessary.  Refs to DOM nodes are more useful, because you may need to do things like determining if a click is inside a DOM node, or read a value from an uncontrolled input.  Refs to components have a lot fewer use cases.  In particular, directly calling methods on components is definitely not idiomatic React usage, and should be avoided if at all possible.  From there, groveling into the guts of React's implementation is a *really* bad idea.

If you need to make use of a nested child's data in a parent component, and those are widely separated, then you should either pass some kind of callback prop down through all those children, or you should dispatch a Redux action to put the data into the store and have the parent subscribe to that data.

So yeah, it's hard to tell exactly what you're actually needing to get done from that description and example code, but I can safely say that what you've got there is not the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't think it's avoidable since my child component is loaded dynamically and the dynamically loaded component may or may not have the method I'm looking for.

Really all I want is to display a different component if the ref's method is available.

Another issue is I want to do this at a sibling component level: sibling A receives a prop that's equivalent to the ref of sibling B and can inspect sibling B to see if the method is present and display if appropriate. I'm seeing way too many answers regarding "this isn't the right way" and very few regarding the "right" way.

Comment: Not to mention my ref property isn't even populated until after the initial mount which leaves my sibling A component missing the props it needs to make the determination in the first place.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't be worried about "methods" - you should be doing things based on state.  You could maybe have the dynamically loaded component dispatch an action (or call a callback) that reports what kind of component it is, and have the parent component make decisions based on that.  Similarly, "sibling"-level behavior should usually be "lifted up" to the parent, per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html . But yes, in general, "The React Way" of doing things is to drive your UI based on state, and _not_ directly interact with component instances.

Answer (score 0):

@markerikson there is valid reasons for doing this. React unidirectional data flow is a very important fundamental rule, but just like how the best music breaks some rules (jazz improv), so too do the best React apps break some conventions in very crafty places. For example, Redux and React router must break convention by using context. So too is there valid use cases for using refs and accessing components with refs.

For example: Imagine you have a very complicated text editor component as a parent. You have many child components responsible for the fields such as a contact field a website field and a description field etc. Now, inside each of these child components you frequently update state. Specifically, on every single click of a button you update the state. The product ask is to have all of the fields alive at the same time so you cannot have individual submit buttons on the fields. You must take all of the current state of all fields at the same time. Now, you could manage the state by lifting it to the complicated parent component, but then that means every single time you press a button to re-render any of these fields you are going to have a callback that causes the complex parent to rerender and therefore all other children components.

On the other hand, with the crafty use of the nifty trick component refs we can update the state of all fields completely independently without triggering rerenders in everything, then when the user submits the form we can trigger one function inside the parent that checks the current/final state of all children through refs and submit that value to the database.

The idea of antipatterns comes up in React a lot. You are right to stick to the rules most of the time, but like a jazz pianist takes the standard Saints Go Marching In and breaks some rules to make something more enjoyable to some people, we can take React, a rigid set of conventions and improv on them if it creates a better experience for certain contexts.